# Get the indexes of truthy elements of a boolean list as a list/tuple

Tags: python, json, list

Given a boolean list such as `[True, False, False, True, False, True]`, what is the *quickest* way to get a list/tuple containing the indexes (starting from 1, not zero-indexed) of the Truthy elements in the original list? So for the list above, it should returns `[1, 4, 6]` or `(1, 4, 6)`.

I was using a generator like this:

```
def get_truthy_ones(self, bool_list):
    return (idx + 1 for idx, value in enumerate(bool_list) if value)
```

However, this creates a problem when I want to encode the results in a `JSON` object, as `JSON` does not encode generators.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[i for i, elem in enumerate(bool_list, 1) if elem]
```

Comment: is that a list comprehension then? Would that be the fastest solution?

Comment: @MLister either this or using `numpy`; you'll have to time both to know what's faster, but this one is probably the shortest, and list comprehensions are quite optimized.

Answer (score 3):

Switch the parentheses to square brackets to return a list instead of a generator:

```
def get_truthy_ones(self, bool_list):
    return [idx for idx, value in enumerate(bool_list, 1) if value]
```

Or use your original function and then create a list from the generator:

```
list(get_truthy_ones(self, bool_list))
```

Comment: I never knew `enumerate` had a second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Just because it can be done, an alternative version with `itertools.compress()`. I would argue this is less readable than the other examples, so I wouldn't recommend it.

```
>>> list(itertools.compress(*zip(*enumerate([True, False, False, True, False, True], 1))))
[1, 4, 6]
```

Edit:

```
python -m timeit -s "import itertools" -s "values = [True, False]*10000" "list(itertools.compress(*zip(*enumerate(values, 1))))"
100 loops, best of 3: 2.88 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s "import itertools" -s "values = [True, False]*10000" "[index for index, value in enumerate(values, 1) if value]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 msec per loop
```

Significantly slower, in fact, so definitely not one to use.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a way to convert the list to a numpy array, using numpy.where() should be faster:

```
> python -m timeit -s "import numpy" -s "values = numpy.array([True, False]*10000)" "numpy.where(values)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 392 usec per loop

> python -m timeit -s "import itertools" -s "values = [True, False]*10000" "[index for index, value in enumerate(values, 1) if value]"
100 loops, best of 3: 2.1 msec per loop
```

But I may be cheating here by doing the conversion in the setup.

Comment: Beat me to it (usning numpy)...but if you move the numpy.array part out of the setup, its slower.